# Mocking field in @Mock class

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Since I am new to Mockito, I would like to know, how can I mock a method inside a class, which actually is also annotated with `@Mock`.

Example:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class someServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
private MainService mainService;

@Mock
private HelpService helpService;

@Mock
private SecondHelpService secondHelpService;
```

Now there is this `helpService` class, which contains a method, which is used to test `MainService`.

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class HelpService {

//  I want this method to be mocked
private boolean checkSomething(String name, date) {
    return ProcessService.checkIfJobHasRun(name, date);
}
```

I tried to use `@InjectMocks` on `HelpService` as well, by adding `ProcessService` `@Mock` in `someServiceTest`, but Mockito doesn't allow that. And as a result, it throws me `NullPointerException`. How do I fix that?

Comment: You need to use PowerMocks to mock private or local methods

Comment: Why would you want to mock a private method of a dependency of a class under test? SomeService cannot call that method directly anyway.. mock the public method of Helpservice that contains the call to the private method

Comment: This means extra library. I can make the method public as well. But I dont understand, how I can mock it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@InjectMocks` should only be used on the class under test. It does not make sense to inject dependencies into mocks as they do not have any implementation.

If you can make the method public you could mock it as follows:

```
doReturn(true).when(helpService)
              .checkSomething(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(Date.class));
```